# Digit Dictionary by Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am an undergraduate student who loves programming very much. I meet a problem in my exercise and I don't know how to solve it.

The problem is in the following:

Given a list of positive integers, return a dictionary containing the digits 1-9 as keys and the numbers that start with that digit as values. Note: not all digits may be used

Example:

```
Input: [12, 34, 22, 24, 55, 67, 108, 999] 

Output: {1: [12, 108], 2: [22, 24], 3: [34], 5: [55], 6: [67], 9: [999] }
```

Example 2:

```
Input: [10, 20, 30, 40] 

Output: {1: [10], 2: [20], 3: [30], 4: [40]}
```

My answer is like this:

```
def digit_dictionary(nums):
    num = nums.split(',')
    list_num = []
    for i in range(1,10):
        if i == nums[0]:
            list.update({i:nums[0]})
    return list_num
```

The test cases are like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/grade/run/test.py", line 12, in test_sparse_2
    self.assertEqual(digit_dictionary(n), a)
  File "/grade/run/bin/digit_dictionary.py", line 2, in digit_dictionary
    num = nums.split(',')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split
```

as well as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/grade/run/test.py", line 19, in test_sparse
    self.assertEqual(digit_dictionary(n), a)
  File "/grade/run/bin/digit_dictionary.py", line 2, in digit_dictionary
    num = nums.split(',')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

as well as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/grade/run/test.py", line 33, in test_full
    self.assertEqual(digit_dictionary(n), a)
  File "/grade/run/bin/digit_dictionary.py", line 2, in digit_dictionary
    num = nums.split(',')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

as well as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/grade/run/test.py", line 26, in test_empty
    self.assertEqual(digit_dictionary(n), a)
  File "/grade/run/bin/digit_dictionary.py", line 2, in digit_dictionary
    num = nums.split(',')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I had searched about dictionaries of Python but I am still confused. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: The input is a list, as the error message keeps telling you. You don't need to split a list on a comma to get its elements.

Comment: Why are you trying to split a list?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I haven't realized that I should not split this list as I did this exercise... Thank you all for your patience to my mistake as a beginner.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `gropby()` with a sorted list:

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [12, 34, 22, 24, 55, 67, 108, 999]

f = lambda x: int(str(x)[0])
l = sorted(l, key=f)
{k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(l, key=f)}
# {1: [12, 108], 2: [22, 24], 3: [34], 5: [55], 6: [67], 9: [999]}
```

Answer (score 2):

So, you are getting an error because you are trying to perform split on a list object whose type is an integer.
Moreover you are initializing your dictionary beforehand which I think is a wrong practice.

You could try below code:

```
input_list = [1,2,22,111,987,234]
output_dict = dict()

for element in input_list:
   # Using if-else in order to create dict keys at run time.
   if int(str(element)[0]) in output_dict:
      output_dict[int(str(element)[0])].append(element)
   else:
      output_dict[int(str(element)[0])] = [element]

print output_dict
```

Output:

```
{1: [1, 111], 9: [987], 2: [2, 22, 234]}
```

Another Approach (Using `defaultdict`)

```
from collections import defaultdict
input_list = [1,2,22,111,987,234]
output_dict = defaultdict(list)

for element in input_list:
   # In place of if-else using defaultdict
   output_dict[int(str(element)[0])].append(element)

print output_dict
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {1: [1, 111], 2: [2, 22, 234], 9: [987]})
```

Hope this answers your question!!!

Comment: Simple `int` will solve the problem. Edited the solution. Thanks for mentioning @taurus05

Comment: we have `dict.setdefault` method, `if`-`else` block is unnecessary

Comment: Added another approach. Thanks for the insight @AzatIbrakov

Answer (score 1):

First things first. A much better way to do the same, with a minimal amount of code:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> arr =  [12, 34, 22, 24, 55, 67, 108, 999]
>>> dicto = defaultdict(list)
>>> for val in arr:
...     dicto[int(str(val)[0])].append(val)
...
>>> dicto
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [12, 108], 3: [34], 2: [22, 24], 5: [55], 6: [67], 9: [999]})
```

Now, moving on to your code, assuming that the parameter you pass to the function is a list of numeric values, seperated by comma, here is a corrected version of your code.

```
def digit_dictionary(nums):
    d = dict()
    for i in range(1,10):
       temp_list = []
       for num in nums:  
           if i == int(str(num)[0]):   
               temp_list.append(num)
       if temp_list != []:
          d[i] = temp_list
    return d
```

You can compare both the codes and see, that the former uses just a single iteration over the elements of the array of numbers, while the other makes 10 iterations over the list of numbers. If the list is too big (say 10<sup>6</sup> elements), then doing such a blunder will add to extra computation time. Hence, i will recommend you to see how [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) works and start using it.

Comment: That's a nice code dump, but it explains neither the error nor the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
input_list= [12, 34, 22, 24, 55, 67, 108, 999] 
output={}
cur=None
prev=None
l=[]
for i in input_list:
    cur=int(str(i)[0])
    if cur==prev:
        output[int(str(i)[0])].append(i)
    else:
        output[int(str(i)[0])]=[i]
    prev=cur
print(output)
```